# How to format json in wicket dataview using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, apache, wicket-6

I am trying to display a json data in Wicket DataView. If i want to display the json with indentation, how i can achieve this using java script?

I could find many sources to pretty format the json but they  are using java script. How we can call a function to javascript from inside dataview populateItem method to format the json as described in the link  http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/

Html

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr wicket:id="notificationDetails">
      <td valign="top"><span  wicket:id="name"></span></td>
      <td valign="top"><span  wicket:id="value"></span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My Java:

```
    dataView = new ListView<DataForTable>("notificationDetails",dataForTableList) 
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  protected void populateItem(final ListItem<DataForTable> item) 
  {
    item.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<DataForTable>(item.getModel()));
    item.add(new Label("name"));
    item.add(new Label("value"));
  }
};
```

I have also tried to use Jackson object mapper to format the json before adding to Label, but it does not help. The wicket page displays like this

```
mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(value);
```

The wicket page displays like this

```
 {\r\n \"action\" : \"add\",\r\n \"schedule\"...
```

Can you please help to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use MultilineLabel instead of Label so `\n` is replaced with `<br/>`. You can also replace `\t` with `&nbsp;` or any other space character. In this case use `MultilineLabel#setEscapeModelStrings(false)`.